# How to convert scala Array to Java array []

Tags: scala

I have java package
There is Host class and Client class that can reveive many hosts

```
public final class Host {
   public final String name;
   public final int port; 
} 

public class SomeClient{...
   public Client(Host... hosts) throws Exception {
  ....
}
```

I'm writing scala code to creating this client

```
//  the hosts example is hosts1,host2,host3
def getClient(hosts:String) :SomeClient ={
   val default_port:Int = 100
   val hostsArr: Array[String] =hosts.split(",")
   new Client (hostArr ???)
 }
```

How can I map and convert scala array of strings to Host[], so the client will be created properly?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
def getClient(hosts:String): SomeClient = {

    val default_port:Int = 100
    val hostsArr: Array[String] = hosts.split(",")

    //Here you map over array of string and create Host object for each item 
    val hosts = hostsArr map { hostStr =>
        val host = new Host()
        //Rest of assignment

        host
    }

    new Client(hosts:_*)
}
```

You can check the scala reference for [repeated parameters](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf) section `4.6.2`

Answer (score 0):

So, actually your Scala array is already a Java array. You need to map your string array to Host array like:

```
val hosts = hostsArr.map { h => 
   val host = new Host()
   host.name = h
   host.port = default_port

   host
}

new Client(hosts)
```

Comment: That's doesn't compiles with (Host... hosts) signature :-( I need to convert it to Host[] somehow ...

Comment: Hm. I think, I forgot varargs: new Client(hosts : _*) ?

Answer (score 0):

I have provided the basic Scala example of the Elasticsearch client [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54975655/create-java-resthighlevelclient-in-elastic-cluster-mode/64484196#64484196), where it accepts many hosts/nodes(Array/List of hosts) as a parameter. I have used `Java Varargs(:_*)` as mentioned by @Fatih Donmez.