# Create java RestHighLevelClient in elastic cluster mode

Tags: elasticsearch

If elasticsearch runs on single mode, I can easily establish the RestHighLevel connection with this line of code:

```
RestHighLevelClient client = new RestHighLevelClient(
    RestClient.builder(
            new HttpHost("localhost", 9200, "http"),
            new HttpHost("localhost", 9201, "http")));
```

But if my elastic cluster has 3 machines, e.g., "host1", "host2", "host3", how to create the rest high level client in cluster mode ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
RestHighLevelClient client = new RestHighLevelClient(
        RestClient.builder(
                new HttpHost("host1", 9200, "http"),
                new HttpHost("host2", 9200, "http"),
                new HttpHost("host2", 9200, "http")
        )
);
```

As the [doc it looks like you were referencing states](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/master/java-rest-high-getting-started-initialization.html), RestClient.builder accepts an array of HttpHosts to connect to.  The client (which under the hood is the ES low-level REST client) will round-robin requests to these hosts.  See also the [Javadoc](https://artifacts.elastic.co/javadoc/org/elasticsearch/client/elasticsearch-rest-client/6.6.1/org/elasticsearch/client/RestClient.html#builder(org.apache.http.HttpHost...)).

Answer (score 0):

As per the [Elasticsearch docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/master/java-rest-low-usage-initialization.html) you can pass multiple Elasticsearch hosts in `RestClient.builder()`.

The better solution is to load the Elasticsearch hosts from configuration(`application.conf` in case of Scala-based application) instead of hardcoding it in the codebase.

Here is the Scala-based solution using `Java Varargs(:_*)`.

**application.conf**

```scala
es_hosts = ["x.x.x.x","x.x.x.x","x.x.x.x"] // You can even use service-name/service-discovery
es_port = 9200
es_scheme = "http"
```

**Code snippet**

```scala
import collection.JavaConverters._
import com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory
import org.apache.http.HttpHost
import org.elasticsearch.client.{RestClient, RestHighLevelClient}


val config = ConfigFactory.load()
val port = config.getInt(ES_PORT)
val scheme = config.getString(ES_SCHEME)

val es_hosts = config.getStringList(ES_HOSTS).asScala
val httpHosts = es_hosts.map(host => new HttpHost(host, port, scheme))

val low_level_client = RestClient.builder(httpHosts:_*)
val high_level_client: RestHighLevelClient = new RestHighLevelClient(low_level_client)
```

Answer (score 0):

To create High level REST client using multiple hosts, you can do something like following:

```
String[] esHosts = new String[]{"node1-example.com:9200", "node2-example.com:9200", 
    "node3-example.com:9200"};

final ClientConfiguration clientConfiguration = ClientConfiguration.builder()
    .connectedTo(esHosts)
    .build();

RestHighLevelClient restClient = RestClients.create(clientConfiguration).rest();

// Hostnames used for building client can be verified as following
List<Node> nodes = restClient.getLowLevelClient().getNodes();
nodes.forEach(node -> System.out.println(node.toString()));
```

References:

- Docs for [High Level REST Client](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current/reference/html/#elasticsearch.clients.rest)
- Source code for [`ClientConfigurationBuilder`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/elasticsearch/client/ClientConfigurationBuilder.java#L70)

Answer (score 0):

I am creating my elastic REST client with below steps:

```
RestHighLevelClient client=null;
List<HttpHost> hostList = new ArrayList<>();
 for (String host : hosts) {
 String[] hostDetails  = host.split("\\:");hostList.add(new 
 HttpHost(hostDetails[0],Integer.parseInt(hostDetails[1]),https));
}
try(RestHighLevelClient client1 = new RestHighLevelClient(
          RestClient.builder(hostList.toArray(new 
 HttpHost[hostList.size()]))
                  .setHttpClientConfigCallback(
                          httpClientBuilder ->
 // to do this only if auth is enabled                                   
 httpClientBuilder.setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider)))) 
 {
  client = client1;
  }
 } catch (IOException e) {
  log.error("exception occurred while setting elastic client");
 }
```